# Need help understanding Groovy Lists

Tags: groovy

I am new to the Groovy language. Can someone please explain to me what this line of code means?

```
List<String> somevar = [].withDefault { }
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's not a map, it's a list

Comment: Hi Tim - what does the .withDefault{ } do?  Does it initialize a new element with a Space character?

Answer (score 1):

As it says in [the documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#withDefault(groovy.lang.Closure)):

> Decorates a list allowing it to grow when called with a non-existent index value. When called with such values, the list is grown in size and a default value is placed in the list by calling a supplied init Closure

There's a [good blog post about it here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/groovy-goodness-create-list-with.html)

Comment: But, what does it mean when nothing is supplied for the closure, as in the example I supplied?

Comment: @user1104028, when nothing is supplied `null` value will be used as default.

Answer (score 1):

It gives a default value for elements not yet in the list. For example

```
List<String> somevar = [].withDefault { }
println "Value at index 0 is "+somevar[0]; // gives null
println "Value at index 5 is "+somevar[5]; // gives null

List<String> somevarb = ['a'].withDefault { 'b' };
println "Value at index 0 is "+somevarb[0]; // gives a
println "Value at index 5  is "+somevarb[5]; // gives b
```

So when its empty like in your case it gives **null**. 
Read more [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.ke/2012/10/groovy-goodness-create-list-with.html)